# Plotting pcolormesh with a bunch of 2-d arrays with different color

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Here is my question

### Sorry for the confused expression.

### Just check my update. It's more clear.

#### 1. Intro

- 3-d numpy-array *"data"* with the shape of (10, 31, 37).
- The first dimension 10 is the number of the 2-d arrays
- The last 2 arrays represent some grid value of 2-d area with the value of 0 & 1

It shows like this:

```
### mask the value 0 of data[1,:,:]
data_mask = np.ma.masked_less(data[[1,:,:],0.001)
pc =plt.pcolor(xx,yy,data_mask[i,:,:],alpha =1,facecolor = "pink",edgecolor = 'steelblue',zorder =3)
## plotting the grid line
mesh =plt.pcolor(xx,yy,data[1,:,:],cmap="gray",alpha =0.45,facecolor = "none",edgecolor = 'k')
```

[image: Sorry, China don't allow me using imgur]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i8.tietuku.com/f3573868c548d7e3.png))</sub>

#### 2. My attempt

- Plotting each 2-d array with different color in one figure
- If it's possible to plot the cross-section part in another color(like venn diagram) or filling type("hatch"), :

[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i8.tietuku.com/3f39c4b125286324.png))</sub>

#### 3. My code

Two 2-d array for example.
[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i8.tietuku.com/7b8b67f8422631e1.png))</sub>

```
cs=plt.cm.jet(np.arange(2)/2.)     
for i in range(0,2,1):
    data_mask = np.ma.masked_less(data[i,:,:],0.001)
    plt.pcolor(xx,yy, data_mask[i,:,:],alpha =0.95,facecolor = cs[i],edgecolor = 'k',zorder =3)
```

*result*
[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i8.tietuku.com/13092a81a118e180.png))</sub>

These figure all seemed that the color setting was wrong.

#### 4. My question

> 1. How to set the pcolor grid color? In my example, using `facecolor =`  didn't work. And I know  using `cmap = plt.cm.xxx`  works(picture below). But I must plot this two 2-d array separately.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i8.tietuku.com/3c1ccd7252476678.png))</sub>

> 2. As I said in *'My attempt 2'*, Is there a method to testify the overlapping and label these grid in some smart way.

What I can figure out was generating another np.array named 'overlap' and save the information of each grid

```
for i in range(0,data.shape[1],1):
    for j in range(0,dat.shape[2],1):
        if (data[0,i,j] == 1) & (data[1,i,j] == 1.0):
            overlap[i,j] = 1
```

When there are more than two 2-d array, this method couldn't cope with.

## Update -2016-01-17

I summarize my question into one figure with the code which generate it:

```
cover_mask = np.ma.masked_less(data[0,:,:],0.001)
plt.pcolor(xx,yy,data_mask[0,:,:],cmap = plt.cm.Set1,alpha =0.75,\
           edgecolor = 'k',zorder =3)      

cover_mask = np.ma.masked_less(cov[1,:,:],0.001)       
plt.pcolor(xx,yy,cover_mask[1,:,:],cmap = plt.cm.Set2,alpha =0.75,\
           edgecolor = 'k',zorder =3)
```

http://i4.tietuku.com/1d47a3410417cd4f.png

#### My question

1. In the code above, I plot the 2-d arrays separately. If the grid color can be set using `facecolor = 'cs[i]'` with `cs=plt.cm.xxx(np.arange(2)/2.)`   , I can loop all of my data[0:10,:,:].But I can only use `cmap = xxx` to differ each array's color. **I don't know how to loop the colormap.**
2. In the picture above, the red grids and the green grids are overlapped. For better visualization effect, I want to label these overlapping grids striked.

*Idea 1*

- each 2-d grids has different colors and all overlapping area share the same color(In my case, 11 colors are needed)

*Idea 2*

label the overlapping grid wiht 'X' or something esle like the figure below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i8.tietuku.com/881c1aacdddd9258.png))</sub>

#### Add

Based on this [post](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3058), it seems that 'pcolor/pcolormesh' don't have the function of setting `hatch = '* '`.

Comment: There are 10 2d arrays, so you need 2**10 colors to represent overlap. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't used numpy color plots before.

That said I think I see where your problem is.  From the cmap documentation:

> Typically Colormap instances are used to convert data values (floats) from the interval [0, 1] to the RGBA color that the respective Colormap represents.

I believe the problem is that you're setting all the grid values to 1, and then all the overlap values to 1 as well.  So in a cmap they end up being the same color.  If you want them to be different colors they need to be different values.  Or if you want some value inbetween use a float between 0 and 1.  Setting all the values of one array to 1 and the other to 0, with the overlap cells getting set to 0.5 would give you colors at the opposite end of the cmap with the overlap cells a mix of both (assuming you're using a 2 color cmap).  Revised:

```
for i in range(0,data.shape[1],1):
    for j in range(0,dat.shape[2],1):
        #assuming you've set one array to 0 and the other to 1
        overlap[0, i, j] = abs(data[0, i, j] / data[1, i, j) / 2 
        #if (data[0,i,j] == 1) & (data[1,i,j] == 1.0)
            #overlap[i,j] = 1
```

Hope that answers your question, it was a little confusing.  I appreciate all the information you provided but a clear "This is exactly what is wrong" statement at the beginning would definitely help understand the problem.  And hey let me know if this fixes it because I'm interested.

Comment: Thanks, if I have figured it out. I'll post it on this question and let you know.

Comment: okay I see your updated question.  I think you want to set the value of one array to 0, and the other array to 1.  Then the overlap should be set to 0.5 or some value inbetween.  I think that should make the overlap a mix of the two colors (depending on the cmap) with the original objects being colors of opposite ends of the cmap.  Better than the alpha solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to set overlap cells to one color, then following code works:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import colors

data = (np.random.rand(3, 5, 10) > 0.8).astype(np.int)
cdata = (data * np.arange(1, 4)[:, None, None]).sum(axis=0)
overlap = data.sum(axis=0) > 1
cdata[overlap] = 4

y, x = np.mgrid[:6, :11]

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(["w", "r", "g", "b", "k"])
pl.pcolormesh(x, y, cdata, edgecolor="black", cmap=cmap)
```

The main point is to call `pcolormesh()` only once, and use a `ListedColormap` cmap object to set colors of every cell, here is the output:

[image]

the colors of the arrays are "r", "g", "b", and the overlap color is black. Here is the content of data:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```